# Rails 3 Group Mobile & Tablets w/ User Agent?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mobile, user-agent, tablet

I'm trying to conditionally render/hide some html in one of my views for tablets and mobile devices such as android phones & tablets, iPhone, iPad, etc. So far I have this setup:

```
def mobile_agent?
  request.user_agent =~ /Mobile|webOS/
end
```

This seems to work good, but currently it only supports mobile devices and not tablets. I know [mobile_fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/mobile-fu) groups both mobile devices and tablets under the mobile device category, however it also changes the request format which I don't want. My web application is utilizing a responsive theme so views are meant to work under any device with the exception of an embeded Unity webplayer which I wish to hide in a single view.

Is there any way I can extend the above method to include tablets as well as mobile devices?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I use this one

```
def mobile_agent?
  request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] && request.env["HTTP_USER_AGENT"][/(iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|Android)/]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this: https://github.com/neighborland/mobu

> Mobu provides a Rails controller concern called DetectMobile. Mobu does server-side User Agent detection to categorize requests as mobile, tablet, or default.
>
> Mobu modifies your rails view paths based on the request type. It does not require custom MIME types or separate subdomains.